# Non-deletion of nodes in QGIS

Tags: polygon, editing, qgis-2

I've come across an annoying irritation. I have a .SHP converted from MapInfo which consists of a large number of features, a lot of which are made up of a whole heap of combined/multipart polygons. I'm doing a basic edit in deleting nodes. I get down to 2/3 nodes and then it won't let me delete them no matter what I do. The undo/redo indicates nothing is happening. Have tried removing and bringing up again. No issues until the last few nodes - seems to work ok prior, edit, select a number of ways, click node tool, click, click again, goes blue and doesn't do anything. It shivers but that's about it. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Ahaaa...."After selecting vertices for deletion, click the Delete key. Note that you cannot use the mActionNodeTool Node Tool to delete a complete feature; QGIS will ensure it retains the minimum number of vertices for the feature type you are working on. To delete a complete feature use the mActionDeleteSelected Delete Selected tool."

Comment: Have you used the tool Check Geometry in the Vector menu?

Comment: What is `large`in your case? Maybe this question leads you to use another file format: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79850/merge-large-number-of-polygons-using-qgis

Comment: Not overly large,  about 100 individual line items with a maximum of 30 polygons in some so shouldn't be a problem. Just restarted app and the offending item seems to have disappeared (did try this before). Strange. Will use check geometry next time. I can delete through the table but as they are multi-polys not really an option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the Node Tool to delete a complete feature; QGIS will ensure it retains the minimum number of vertices for the feature type you are working on. To delete a complete feature use the Delete Selected tool."