# How to create dissolved buffers using QGIS virtual layers?

Tags: qgis, buffer, spatialite, virtual-layer

To create dissolved buffers (single geometries) in PostGIS I use ST_Dump and ST_Union:

```
SELECT 
    row_number() over() AS gid,
    sbqry.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        (ST_Dump(ST_Union(ST_Buffer(input_layer.geom, 100)))).geom::geometry(Polygon, 31256) AS geom
    FROM input_layer
) AS sbqry;
```

As far as I know QGIS virtual layers are based on SpatiaLite. So at least ST_Dump isn't supported. Is there a SpatiaLite equivalent to the query posted above?

Comment: Did you try the Dissolve feature embeded in QGIS, **Vector > GeoProcessing Tools > Dissolve**

Comment: I want to create the geometries dynamically.

Comment: Using programming or commands ? as using ogr2ogr you can dissolve dynamically with the help of spatialite. http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, but that could be a start: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=VirtualElementary

Comment: You'll need to use dot macro commands.  In this article, there is a section - 'useful in order to resolve complex Geometries into many distinct rows (more or less equivalent to PostGIS's own ST_Dump)' - which should be what you need.  Link to article: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=dot+macros.  Is this helpful?

Answer (score 2):

For ST_Dump, there are roughly equivalent dot macro commands found here: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=dot+macros, under the section: 'useful in order to resolve complex Geometries into many distinct rows (more or less equivalent to PostGIS's own ST_Dump)'.

---

For ST_Union:  According to this article: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spatialite-users/FTO_cmLCfpE/HCLil1hzjgoJ, ST_Union is not working properly in 4.3.0 but will be fixed in 4.4.0.  The workaround until that release is:

---

Original Query:

`Select f.field1 as field1, st_union(f.geometry) as geometry
From tableA as f
Group by field1;`

Workaround:

`Select f.field1 as field1, st_unaryunion(st_collect(f.geometry)) as geometry
From tableA as f
Group by field1;`

---

This information about the workaround came from this post: [What is the efficient way to dissolve polygons using Spatialite 3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35213/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-dissolve-polygons-using-spatialite-3-0)

Comment: Hi jbalk, can you post a sample query for dissolved buffers (single geometries) in SpatiaLite?

Comment: I already have in my answer.